# Justify text in markdowns jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, justify, static-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm using Jekyll. On markdowns I want to justify text, I can do it using CSS but i don't want to include HTML inside markdowns, is any possible way to justify text, any Jekyll code or something like that ?

Answer (score 6):

In Kramdown, you can add [block attributes](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) like id, class, ...
Here we add a `text-justify` class to our `p` block :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
{: .text-justify}
```

And your css does the rest :

```
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```